# Error detail not sent by server AspnetBoilerPlate

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrQ9Y.png)[image]

In Aspnet Boilerplate, Swagger-UI is running at port no 5000 and the angular require port no 21021. so am facing problems.

I tried Changing port number in angular code but then it was displaying

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

So please help me to solve my issue

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Which asp.net boilerplate do you use (asp.net MVC or asp.net core)? May be you need to enable cors from web api code.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check` error you need to sent back the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

As I do not know which version you are running (either MVC or the Core version), I assume you are using the MVC version.

Override the `Application_OnBeginRequest` method in `global.asax.cs`:

Example:

```
protected void Application_OnBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Reading out response.
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    // Setting CORS headers.
    response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

Keep in mind when sending back an `*` as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value. Every host can talk to your API. If you do not want the entire world to access your API simply specify a FQDN as value.